# Delete cell from tableView and data from Firestore iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

I'm making an restaurant app where I have restaurant which contains food. I have the following problem. From each restaurant, I can add food into my shopping cart, but when im trying to swipe left to delete a cell, close the cart and re-enter in the cart, is deleting all the cart, not the cell I have selected for swipping

This is my model :

```
struct Cart
{
    var photoKeyCart: String
    var foodCart: String
    var priceCart: Int
    
    
}
```

This is the function im using for retrieving the data from Firestore and displaying it into the cart. This function is called in the viewdidload() .

```
 func getCartProducts() {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userID = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
        db.collection("CartDatabase").document(userID).collection("CartItems").getDocuments {  (document, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            } else {
                for document in document!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let newEntry = Cart(photoKeyCart: data["photoKeyCart"] as! String, foodCart: data["foodCart"] as! String , priceCart: data["priceCart"] as! Int
                    )
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    self.cart.append(newEntry)
                }
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //  self.datas = self.filteredData
                self.cartTableView.reloadData()
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Viewdidload function :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getCartProducts()
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CartTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        cartTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CartTableViewCell")
        cartTableView.delegate = self
        cartTableView.dataSource = self
        
    }
```

Table view extension :

```
extension CartViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var sum = 0
        
        for item in cart{
            sum += item.priceCart
        }
        
        priceTotalLabel.text = "\(sum) lei"
        return cart.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = cartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CartTableViewCell
        let carts = cart[indexPath.row]
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        let photoRef = storageRef.child(carts.photoKeyCart)
        cell.foodInCartPrice.text = " \(carts.priceCart) lei "
        cell.foodInCartName.text = carts.foodCart
        cell.foodInCartImage.sd_setImage(with: photoRef)
        cell.foodInCartImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.foodInCartImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.foodInCartImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.foodInCartImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.foodInCartImage.frame.height/2
        cell.foodInCartImage.clipsToBounds = true
        
        return cell
        
    }
```

This is the function im using for swiping left and trying to delete the cell, but it deletes all my cells. I think the problem is that is deleting all the data from the database, and when the function is called, it have nothing to retrieve.

Database used : [Tap here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDxY6.png)

Comment: You haven't shown any "delete" code. Also, it isn't really appropriate to calculate the cart total in `numberOfRows`.  You can do that when you fetch or update your data. Why are you storing the cart in firebase anyway.  Is it really the sort of data that needs to be persisted in that way?  Wouldn't a local on-device store be more appropriate?

Comment: Please include images of your Firestore structure in the question. If that link breaks, we'll have no idea what it was. Also `DispatchQueue.main.async` is not needed in firebase closures; UI calls are always in the main thread, networking is on a background thread.